# PHP regex to get filename from URL

Tags: php, regex

I'm not too good with regular expressions, but how would I go about splitting the filename with the extension from the path?

> D:/DCIM/image10.jpg
>
> D:/DCIM/image11.jpg
>
> D:/DCIM/image12.jpg
>
> D:/DCIM/image13.jpg

I would get imagex.jpg from each other the about strings, x being a number.

So basically search for ".jpg" then get all other characters up until the "/".

**Edit:**
Ah the pathinfo function will do the job, although it would be nice to know how to do things like this with a RegEx for future purposes.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Comment: Please provide more examples of inputs and what the expected output should be.

Comment: You might possibly want [dirname](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php).

Comment: "how to do things like this" --- then you need to learn regular expressions. They aren't that trivial so that you could get one here and modify it after without understanding. So you want to get it with regexes - show us your attempts.

Answer (score 6):

From the PHP manual:
You can use the [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) function

```
<?php

$path = pathinfo('D:/DCIM/image10.jpg');
echo $path['filename'];

?>
```

or you can use the [basename](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) function to get it with the extension without bothering in catching both (filename and extension) from pathinfo result array:

```
<?php
echo basename('D:/DCIM/image10.jpg');
?>
```

Good luck!

**EDIT**

If you insist, try this

```
<?php

$files = array(
    "D:/DCIM/image11.jpg",
    "C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php",
    "/usr/local/script.sh"
);

foreach ($files as $file) {
    preg_match("/[^\/|\\\]+$/", $file, $matches);
    var_dump($matches);   
}
?>
```

Where

```
[^\/|\\\]
```

means that you start searching for a slash, escaping the slash character with a backslash

```
[^\/
```

or you start searching a backslash escaping the backslash and the bracket characters with a backslash.

```
|\\\]
```

In the end, you search for anything, at least once, in the end of the given string.

```
+$
```

I took the concept from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045122/regex-that-matches-the-last-occurrence-of-a-character?answertab=votes#tab-top)
I hope it helps!

Comment: Just beware of utf-8 file name. See this bug https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47954

Comment: Is valid test this use case (UTF-8 filename) in the version of php of those who use this function. In my case, works like a champ! Thanks for the tip @Orion

Answer (score 1):

Regexs are quite complex, especially for this sort of task, so I'd have to recommend avoiding them as it's bad practise to use, unless you absolutely have to.

The best options are either something simple using explode.

```
$parts = explode('/', $url);
```

Now `$parts[count($parts) - 1]` will contain the filename.

Or using `pathinfo`

```
$filename = pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

Now `$filename` contains the filename.

That being said, if you know the full path, you could use `str_replace` or even `substr`. All options are a bit messy, but they're better than regexs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a RegEx, use `preg_match_all` with `[^/]+\b$`. I'll leave the specifics up to you. Personally I'd use `pathinfo` as posted by zerkms though.

This RegEx looks for a group of character(s) that *are not* a "/" and are proceeded by end of string.