# A quick way to find the first and last indexes of a substring

Tags: python, string, indexing

Is there a function that automatically finds the first and last indexes of a string? I would like to do the finding once without zipping the two indexes.

The code below finds the first and last indexes of the word 'best' within string 'txt', however, it does it separately.

```
>>> _txt='my best friend'
>>> _str='best'

>>> _txt.find(_str)  # first index
3

>>> _txt.find(_str[-1]) # last index 
6

#Attempt on joining 
1) >>>_txt.find(_str),(_str[-1])
(3, 't')
```

The output from the attempt is wrong.

Ideal output:

```
(3,6)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you wanted to do `_txt.find(_str),_txt.find(_str[-1])`, why don't you just define a function or lambda that takes two params?

Comment: What if the input is `the best friend`?

Comment: `_txt.find(_str[-1])` does not do what you think it does. It finds the first index of the last character of `_str` in `_txt`; if `_txt` is `'aabb'` and `_str` is `'abb'`, this will give 2, rather than 3.

Comment: @EdChum, thefoutheye just raised a very important observation. you suggestion would not work if the input is 'the best friend'

Comment: You can use regular expressions: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045122/regex-that-matches-the-last-occurrence-of-a-character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is only one match, then you can do this:

```
start = _txt.find(_str)
end = start + len(_str) - 1
```

Or, if there are multiple matches, then you can use `re.finditer`:

```
matches = [(m.start(0), m.end(0) - 1) for m in re.finditer(_str, _txt)]
```

Comment: I'm getting [(4, 8)] instead of [(4, 7)]. The end is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
_str ='My best friend.'
getIndexes = lambda x: (_str.find(x[:-len(x)+1]),_str.find(x[len(x)-1:]))
print getIndexes('best')
```

You can't get any "quicker" than using a lambda function and retrieving the indexes of the substring locally.

Comment: You're just getting (0, len-1). That's not the question.

Comment: Still wrong; you're just searching for the first and last characters of the 'pattern' and not the entire thing.

Comment: "my bes t best friend" gives (3, 7) instead of (9, 12). "my tbes best friend" gives (4, 3). The reason might be clearer if you simplify your indexing: `x[:-len(x)+1]` is just `s[0]`; `x[len(x)-1:]` is just `x[-1]`. Perhaps you want`x[:-1]` and `x[1:]`, but that would still be broken - "My bes t best friend" will give (3, 10). Even if this did work, I'm quite sure that the other answer, involving *one* linear search and some simple arithmetic, will be quite a bit quicker than a solution involving *two* linear searches and string manipulation. More importantly, it is *much* simpler code to read.

Comment: I understood the problem perfectly with the "tbes". Thank you very much!